# webpack unable to load typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I am using webpack-4 in one of my projects. I have a class declared as:

```
export abstract class Base {
...
}
```

I have type definition for this file stored in typings/index.d.ts as:

```
export declare abstract class Base {
    constructor();
    ...
}
```

and in another typescript file when I try to import the type Base from type definition liek this:

```
import { Base } from '../../../typings/index';
```

webpack throws error like:

> ERROR in /app/cratejoy/static/ts/edit-shipment.ts Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve '../../../typings/index' in
>   '/app/cratejoy/static/ts'  @ /app/cratejoy/static/ts/edit-shipment.ts

However, if I try to run tsc compiler manually, like this:

```
tsc cratejoy/static/ts/edit-shipment.ts
```

It compiles fine and I don't see any errors. I have updated my tsconfig.json with:

```
"files": [
    "./typings/index.d.ts"
]
```

But webpack stil complains with the error above. I am not sure why build via webpack is unable to pick up the type definition from d.ts in typings/index.d.ts.

Comment: what do you use as loader in your webpack config ?

Comment: @adz5A I use ts-loader.